# Drag and copy text from panel to canvas in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, drag-and-drop

I am trying to drag item from treeview to a panel.

The treeview item is a StackPanel consisting of an Image and a Label.

How should i get the text in the Label when drag the treeview item into the PanelDragDropTarget?

Answer (score 0):

Got some answer but is kind of lousy.

I get the type of UIElement being dragged,

if Label then get its Content

if Image then get its Parent and search for the Label and get its Content.